# R.Watershed unable to process a large geotiff (dem) file

Tags: grass-gis, r.watershed

I have a large geotiff file (dem) that I am planning to use with r.watershed to delineate a very large drainage basin.  The file is 142 GB. When I try to run r.watershed after a few second it gives me error messages (ex: unable to write ...).  I tried a different approach by clipping a small portion of the geotiff and run r.watershed again.  This time r.watershed runs properly, and all the support output files are created.  My question, is there a way to process a large geotiff in r.watershed?

Answer (score 1):

When reading the documentation at https://grass.osgeo.org/grass73/manuals/r.watershed.html

It says you should use the **-m** flag so that the process is not run in memory. This will make the processing slower, but it should work if you have sufficient disk space.

Comment: Ok I will try and let the group know about the results.